# Pro*c Configuring for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, oracle, visual-studio-2019, oracle-pro-c

Recently for an old project, I started learning Pro*C. I am following [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/proc#Restrictions) tutorial.
But at the end of the tutorial during debugging my program shows an error.

[image: Pro*c error on VS2019]

It seems that Pro*c configuration is not correct in visual studio 2019. I tried to google to adjust the setup & only found 1 that related to [VS 2017](https://taisou.tistory.com/633) but in the Chinese language. Any help regarding Pro*c development on VS 2019?